# How to fix php adding a plain row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a small project and I'm having some trouble with a php script. Basically, when they enter the text then click 'Enter' It loads to the 'insert.php'. The thing is, if they just visit the insert.php page without going to the main page It enters a plan table which could cause big problems.

Code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","info","info","info");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Can you help me fix this problem as It could cause a lot of troubles.

Comment: (1) Validate before insertion (2) **prevent MySQL injection!!!!** (3) Only do something if `$_POST` is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to validate your $_POST variables by using isset().
If they are not submitted from a form, $_POST will be empty. Meaning that when a user try to type in the url, there won't be any post data and your SQL queries won't run.

2nd, you are subject to SQL injection since you are not escaping the content.
I'd suggest escaping each variable by using a prepared statement or mysqli_real_escape_string (less secure but better than nothing).`

```
if ( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['age'])) {
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","info","info","info");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//simple example of escaping variables - BUT NOT AS SECURE AS PREPARED STATEMENT!!
$firstname = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);    
$lastname =  $con->real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);    
$age = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['age']);

//With MySQLi it is best practice to use `prepere`, `bind_param` and `execute: 
//or use PDO.

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$firstname','$lastname','$age')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Lastly, you were missing the single quotes inside your $_POST variables.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Aha, I get this now: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mysqli' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Another typo (fixed). should use $con not $mysqli

Comment: It works now but everytime I load the page It says '1 row added'. Should It? It has no data to be insert.

Comment: Cool, I also just added a !empty() check since you should validate that the data exists and not empty.

Comment: Also note that there are stronger ways to escape data, one of them is using a prepared statement.

Comment: If being strictly correct, validation should be done this way **and also with integrity values in MySQL**, like not allowing empty fields or using **triggers** to validate some data.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple.

```
if(isset($_POST)):
    //all of your code here
endif;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to PHP. Where would this go? I Apologize for being a total noob.

Comment: @user3233939 did you read the `//` comment? this wraps all of your php cod you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if $_POST exists to trigger your sql request
    if (isset($_POST)){
    //script
    }

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things that I see right off the top of my head is the fact that you are not checking to ensure that something has infact been typed Into your input box that passes the data to your other file. You can try to use isset() or array_key_exist(). Not to mention these are things that you should be doing anyway.